# How Hitachi projector interface C#

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlrp7.png)

Even if I send the required text during the development of the beam projector power-on/off interface, no response will be received. Can you tell me what caused it?

Referring to the RS-232 Communication Command Table, the command was uploaded as an image.

The required command type byte array was passed to the socket, but the failure message or response was not received, causing it to fall into the atmosphere.

The document is supposed to give a failure message if it is a malformed request...

I need feedback on whether I am sending the wrong command or not.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ0fK.png)

---

```
-- SEND
byte[] data = ConvertHexStringToByte("BE EF 03 06 00 19 D3 02 00 00 60 00 00");
int bytesSent = sck.Send(data);
int bytesRec = sck.Receive(bytes);
```

....... NOT Receive

```
public static byte[] ConvertHexStringToByte(string convertString)`
{ 
   byte[] convertArr = new byte[convertString.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < convertArr.Length; i++)
    {
         convertArr[i] = Convert.ToByte(convertString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
  return convertArr;
};
```

Comment: You're actually converting `"BE"`, then `" E"`, then `"03"` and so on. I would rather split the input string, foreach it, and then convert and add in array each elements

Comment: Even if you put the Hex value directly into the byte[] array, it looks the same.

Comment: Could you please edit your question so that it explains what you are trying to achieve, what you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know if it's the format you want, but I've edited the main points of the goals and questions.